# Python and Pyinstaller: include binary application in code

Tags: python, pyinstaller, hwid

I have a small app. For protection I use c:/hwid.exe. The application returns HWID of pc. example code:

```
def HWID_LIC():
    try:
        if hashlib.md5(open('c:\hwid.exe', 'rb').read()).hexdigest() != 'bca173dc':
            sys.exit(1)
        out = os.popen("c:\hwid.exe").read().strip()
        if out not in lic:
            sys.exit(1)
    except:
        sys.exit(1)

HWID_LIC()
```

I want to include hwid.exe in my application and need the solution all in one file. Is possible to do this in Python? hwid.exe has 30 kb.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible. You need to search your hwid.exe in sys._MEIPASS

```
import sys
import os
import hashlib

def HWID_LIC():
    if os.path.isfile('hwid.exe'):
        print('file found in .')
    else:
        print('file not found in .')

    if os.path.isfile(sys._MEIPASS + os.sep + 'hwid.exe'):
        print('file found in sys._MEIPASS')
    else:
        print('file not found')
    print(hashlib.md5(open(sys._MEIPASS + os.sep + 'hwid.exe', 'rb').read()).hexdigest())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    HWID_LIC()
```

Example spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
a = Analysis(['test.py'],
             pathex=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             runtime_hooks=None)
import platform
if platform.system().find("Windows")>= 0:
    a.datas = [i for i in a.datas if i[0].find('Include') < 0]
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not x[0].startswith("scipy")]
a.binaries = [x for x in a.binaries if not x[0].startswith("numpy")]
a.datas += [('hwid.exe','.\\hwid.exe','DATA'),]
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='test.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          clean=True,
          upx=False,
          console=True)
```

and create the onefile exe whith

```
pyinstaller t_onefile.spec
```

When executing test.exe you see:

```
j:\tmp>test.exe
file not found in .
file found in sys._MEIPASS
754222d71581010a45732c471437ecf7
```